# getcomputedstyle only the changes from default

Tags: javascript

The code I currently have gets the whole CSS, even the default one. What I want is to get only the CSS changed from default.

```js
function baba() {
  addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("ex");
    cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null)
    var txt = "";

    for (i = 0; i < cssObj.length; i++) {
      cssObjProp = cssObj.item(i)
      txt += cssObjProp + " = " + cssObj.getPropertyValue(cssObjProp) + "<br>";

      document.getElementById("empty").innerHTML = txt;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<p id="ex" onclick="baba()">Hello World</p>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p id="empty"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changed from default"? Different than the browser default? Or the difference between inline styles and the styles from the stylesheet?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Are you saying that (for instance) for the `h1` you don't want to get the `display` style because it has the default value for `h1` elements (`block`)? Perhaps show us what you expect to see (although in this example, *everything* is the default, so...)

Comment: You might need to create two objects and compare them yourself. Use a loop. It's a good question.

Comment: What you are asking for is the difference between `getComputedStyle` and the firefox-only-non-standard `getDefaultComputedStyle` - easy in firefox, not possible in lesser browsers

Comment: @JaromandaX - Sadly, that might be the answer to the question. I suggest posting it as one. :-)

Comment: there is possibly another answer, and that is to parse and process all "author" stylesheets (and inline styles - remembering some style values are inherited) - quite feasible but not something I would ever attempt to do, since there's no reason to do it if you're the author of the stylesheets in question :p

Comment: I don't want to get all the default styling the browser has, but only the edits done on the CSS page.

Comment: we know what you want - you want the "authored" styles (the styles coming from stylesheets and inline styles) - i.e. the ones that are not user agent or user styles - as I said, it's possible in firefox only (by comparing computed and defaultcomputed styles)

Comment: True, but what I am getting right now is all the styles. How do I get only the stylesheet and inline style?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so here's how I'd tackle it. Note: I just slammed this out in the console in 5 minutes; I'm sure there are more efficient ways to handle it, but for PoC this should get you going.

### Requirements Analysis

Really (barring a more specific edge-case application, anyway), what you're asking for is "How does Element `<XXX>`'s current computed style differ from a vanilla object of the same type *in the same context*?" It's nonsensical to ask how it differs from "default" because "default", perforce, is going to be influenced *by* said context (don't agree? Wait for it; I'll 'splain).

Because of this, really what we need to be examining is a `<XXX>` that lacks the effects applied to your target object (consequences of its DOM position, class, id, attributes, predecessors, etc.). The good news is: we can totally fake it! Check it out:

### The Setup

First thing's first, let's get hold of our object. This would be better executed as a function, I know, but for illustrative purposes, work with me here. Let's pick an object you can see the results on right away. Let's see... how about the Search bar at the top of this very page? Hit f12 to pop your console, and you'll see it's name is 'q'. That'll work.

```
// Get the StackOverflow Search field from the top of this page.
var targetDOMElement = document.querySelector('[name="q"]');
// Now, let's get its current style snapshot.
var targetObjsStyles = window.getComputedStyle(targetDOMElement);
// ... and vomit it out to our console, just so we know what we're dealing with.
console.log('ORIGINAL SET (' + Object.keys(targetObjsStyles).length + ' rules):',targetObjsStyles);
```

Capital! Now we have our source object (our "`<XXX>`", if you will).

### The Control

Next, we need something to compare it *against*. Now, being the obedient little boy who was raised Orthodox Scientist that I am, in my mind that's a control. Fortunately, we know plenty about our source object, so let's manufacture one:

```
// Create a new element of the same type (e.g. tagName) as our target
var tempCopyOfTarget = document.createElement(targetDOMElement.tagName);
// Insert it into the context AT THE BEGINNING of the page. Both bits here are important:
// if we create it within a documentFragment (try it) literally every property will 
// be flagged as unique. I suspect this has to do with the client's default 
// renderer, vs. the purity of a abstracted prototype, but I won't lie: I'm guessing.
// It MUST be at the start of the body to avoid silliness like
// body > .first-element ~ xxx { display:none; }
// CSS still won't let us target predecessors/ancestors, alas.
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin', tempCopyOfTarget);
// Now  our new object shares our target's context, get ITS snapshot.
var basicElementsCSS = window.getComputedStyle(tempCopyOfTarget);
console.log('BASELINE (DUMMY OBJECT) SET (' + Object.keys(basicElementsCSS).length + ' rules):',basicElementsCSS);
```

### The Grunt Work

While I'm certain most folks see where I'm going at this point, let's finish her off. Given a testable quantity, and a control, check for deltas.

```
// Create an empty object to store any changes in.
var cleanSetOfStyles = {};
// Objectify our target's style snapshot, and iterate.
Object.entries(targetObjsStyles).forEach(p=>{
    // If a key-value pair exists that matches our control, ignore it. Otherwise,
    // tack it onto our clean object for later perusal.
    if(basicElementsCSS[p[0]] !== p[1]){ 
        cleanSetOfStyles[p[0]] = p[1];
    }
});
```

Awesome! Nice work!

### Conclusion

Now, assuming my hypothesis is correct, we should see within our clean object a set of properties and their corresponding values. The length of this list should be both non-zero, and different than the count contained within the raw sets above (which, the more observant of you will have noticed, WERE the same, in that the browser assigns ALL possible styles' values to an object when a `getComputedStyles` collection is requested.

```
// Display our deltas
console.log('CLEAN SET (' + Object.keys(cleanSetOfStyles).length + ' rules):',cleanSetOfStyles);
// Oh, and always remember to clean up after you make a mess in the lab.
tempCopyOfTarget.remove()
```

What's this!? VICTORY! At least in my environment (which has to factor my browser make, version, active plug-ins, supported features, operating system, etc., etc.; your mileage may vary), I count 116 rules that remain and are acting on our target object. These are the rules that differ from our vanilla, first-line-of-code object we summoned into being for the picoseconds it took the browser to take a gander at it.

### CAVEATS

There's always a catch, isn't there?
This is NOT a foolproof system. I can think of a half dozen ways this will fail off the top of my head (`:empty` modifiers, depending on the scope you're in... `[name="q"] ~ [name="q"]` rules, the insertion of our dummy object now making apply to our target... `:first-of-type` no longer being applicable... all kinds of 'whoopsies'). BUT, I'm prepared to assert all the ones I can think of are both edge cases, and themselves manageable, given proper forethought.

### TLDR

Here's the whole code, copy+pasteable directly into console, if you're so inclined, and sans comments:

```
var targetDOMElement = document.querySelector('[name="q"]');
var targetObjsStyles = window.getComputedStyle(targetDOMElement);
console.log('ORIGINAL SET (' + Object.keys(targetObjsStyles).length + ' rules):',targetObjsStyles)

var tempCopyOfTarget = document.createElement(targetDOMElement.tagName);
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin', tempCopyOfTarget);

var basicElementsCSS = window.getComputedStyle(tempCopyOfTarget);
console.log('BASELINE (DUMMY OBJECT) SET (' + Object.keys(basicElementsCSS).length + ' rules):',basicElementsCSS)

var cleanSetOfStyles = {};
Object.entries(targetObjsStyles).forEach(p=>{
    if(basicElementsCSS[p[0]] !== p[1]){ 
        cleanSetOfStyles[p[0]] = p[1];
    }

});
console.log('CLEAN SET (' + Object.keys(cleanSetOfStyles).length + ' rules):',cleanSetOfStyles);

tempCopyOfTarget.remove()
```

Final note: I know this question is a couple months old, but nobody really answered it outside of "Nope! You're screwed!" 
On the off chance @angels7 still needs the fix, here ya go. Otherwise, "Hi, all you far-out future folk!"